# How to fit a constant using chi squared with errors

Tags: statistics, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a constant using using Chi squared as the fitting statistic. The constant I am trying to fit is not a simple scaling constant but feeds into an equation which output values.

const -> fn -> values and errors

There are tonnes of posts on here about Chi squared tests but I cannot find anything on using this to fit a value and/or the version which allows for data with errors where:

chi2 = (observed - expected) ** 2 / (1 sigma error in observed) ** 2

Could you please let me know how I can do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Lets build a MCVE to solve your question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, special
```

Provided you have two arbitrary functions for the model and the error:

```
def model(x, a):
    return special.expit(a * x) 

def error(x, a):
    return 0.01 * a * (np.abs(x) + 1e-6) + 0.01
```

We can build a wrapper for Chi Square statistic:

```
def loss_factory(x, y):
    def wrapped(a):
        return np.sum(np.power((y - model(x, a)) / error(x, a), 2))
    return wrapped
```

We generate some synthetic data:

```
np.random.seed(12345)
a = 3.5
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
y = model(x, a)
s = error(x, a)
n = s * np.random.normal(size=x.size)
yn = y + n
```

And create the associated loss:

```
loss = loss_factory(x, yn)
```

Now we will minimize the loss wrt parameter `a` knowing `x`, `y` and `s`:

```
solution = optimize.minimize(loss, x0=[3.])
#       fun: 36.084631813621556
#  hess_inv: array([[0.00449676]])
#       jac: array([-3.81469727e-06])
#   message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
#      nfev: 18
#       nit: 8
#      njev: 9
#    status: 0
#   success: True
#         x: array([3.49451316])
```

Which returns both Chi Square (`solution.fun`) and optimal parameter (`solution.x`).

We can check the fit:

[image]

And the optimality of the solution wrt the loss function:

[image]